# Need an help for Updating a form in PHP using PDO

Tags: javascript, database, html, pdo

All columns are in TEXT format apart from the BDid column which is in int. Ive had the code running smoothly with un-preared statements but thought I would update it, with the same data in and the same table.

No errors are returned, but no rows are affected.

The code is not getting any error but the MySQL is not updating

```php
<?php 

  require 'database.php';

  $id = null;
  if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
  }

  if ( null==$id ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
  }

  if ( !empty($_POST)) {
    // keep track validation errors with form fields
    $first_nameError = null;
    $sur_nameError = null;
    $companyError = null;
    $locationError = null;
    $supervisorError = null;
    $departmentError = null;
    $job_descriptionError = null;
    $hire_dateError =null;
    $emailError = null;
    $messageError = null;

    // keep track post values
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $sur_name = $_POST['sur_name'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $supervisor = $_POST['supervisor'];
    $department = $_POST['department'];
    $job_description = $_POST['job_description'];
    $hire_date = $_POST['hire_date'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // validate input for the field
    $valid = true;
    if (empty($first_name)) {
      $first_nameError = 'Please enter Name';
      $valid = false;
    }
    if (empty($sur_name)) {
      $sur_nameError = 'Please enter Name';
      $valid = false;
    }
    if (empty($company)) {
      $companyError = 'Please selest Company';
      $valid = false;
    }
    if (empty($location)) {
      $locationError = 'Please enter Location';
      $valid = false;
    }
    if (empty($department)) {
      $departmentError = 'Please enter Department';
      $valid = false;
    }
    if (empty($job_description)) {
      $job_descriptionError = 'Please enter Job Description';
      $valid = false;
    }
    if (empty($hire_date)) {
      $hire_dateError = 'Please enter Hire Date';
      $valid = false;
    }
    if (empty($email)) {
      $emailError = 'Please enter Email Address';
      $valid = false;
    } else if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
      $emailError = 'Please enter a valid Email Address';
      $valid = false;
    }

    if (empty($message)) {
      $messageError = 'Please enter Message';
      $valid = false;
    }

    // update data  the field in the database
    if ($valid) {
      $pdo = Database::connect();
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $sql = "UPDATE employee  SET first_name = ?,sur_name = ?, company = ?, location = ?, supervisor = ?, 
      department= ?, job_description =  ?, hire_date = ?, email = ?, message = ? WHERE id = ?";
      $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $q->execute(array($id, $first_name, $sur_name, $company, $location, $supervisor, $department,$job_description, $hire_date, $email, $message));
      Database::disconnect();
      header("Location: index.php");
    }
  } else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee where id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $first_name = $data['first_name'];
    $sur_name = $data['sur_name'];
    $company = $data['company'];
    $location = $data['location'];
    $location = $data['supervisor'];
    $department = $data['department'];
    $job_description = $data['job_description'];
    $hire_date = $data['hire_date'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $message = $data['message'];
    Database::disconnect();
  }
?>
```

This my Html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

          <div class="span10 offset1">
            <div class="row">
              <h3>Update a Customer</h3>
            </div>
        This is my form 

            <form class="form-horizontal" action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post">
               <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($first_nameError)?'error':'';?>">
     <label class="control-label"></label>
        <div class="controls">
     <input name="first_name" required placeholder="First Name" 
         title="First Name" value="<?php echo !empty($first_name)?$first_name:'';?>">
      <?php if (!empty($first_nameError)): ?>
        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $first_nameError;?></span>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($sur_nameError)?'error':'';?>">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
      <div class="controls">
  <input name="sur_name" required placeholder="Sur Name" title="Sur Name" 
      value="<?php echo !empty($sur_name)?$sur_name:'';?>">
   <?php if (!empty($sur_nameError)): ?>
        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $sur_nameError;?></span>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>



 <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($companyError)?'error':'';?>">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
      <div class="controls">
  <select name="company" class="company" id="company" style="company" 
    title="Company" required placeholder="Company" value="<?php echo !empty($company)?$company:'';?>">
     <option value="Select.." selected>Select....</option>
          <option>HM</option>
          <option>HRA</option>
          <option>HSG</option>
          <option>HAL</option>
          <option>HBN</option>
          <option>HFR</option>
          <option>HPL</option>
          <option>HRD</option>
          <option>HERS</option>
          <option>HPS</option>
          <option>HEA</option>
        </select>
   <?php if (!empty($companyError)): ?>
        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $companyeError;?></span>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($locationError)?'error':'';?>">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
      <div class="controls">
  <input name="location" required placeholder="Location" title="Location" 
         value="<?php echo !empty($location)?$location:'';?>">
   <?php if (!empty($locationError)): ?>
        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $location;?></span>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($supervisorError)?'error':'';?>">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
      <div class="controls">
  <input name="supervisor" required placeholder="Supervisor" 
    title="Supervisor" value="<?php echo !empty($supervisor)?$supervisor:'';?>">
   <?php if (!empty($supervisorError)): ?>
        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $supervisor;?></span>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($departmentError)?'error':'';?>">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
      <div class="controls">
  <select name="department" size="1" class="department" id="department"  style="department" 
            title="Department " required placeholder="Department" value="<?php echo !empty($department)?$department:'';?>">
            <option value="Select" selected>Select</option>
              <option value="FI">Finace</option>
              <option value="CO">Controlling</option>
              <option value="PP">Production Planning</option>
              <option value="SD">Sale &amp; Distribution &amp;Customer Relationship manager</option>
              <option value="WM">Warehouse Managerment</option>
              <option value="MM">Material Managerment</option>
              <option value="HR">Human Resources</option>
              <option value="QM">Quality Management</option>
              <option value="PM">Plant Maintenance</option>
              <option value="IT">Information Technology</option>
              <option value="BO">Back Office</option>
              <option value="SAP">Administrative Group SAP User</option>
              <option value="SAPKEY">Administrative Group SAP Key User</option>
              <option value="ADMIN">Administrative Group Administrators</option>
              <option value="MGMT">Management</option>
            </select>
   <?php if (!empty($departmentError)): ?>
        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $department;?></span>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>


      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($job_descriptionError)?'error':'';?>">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
      <div class="controls">
  <input name="job_description" required placeholder="Job Description" 
    title="Job Description" value="<?php echo !empty($job_description)?$job_description:'';?>">
   <?php if (!empty($job_descriptionError)): ?>
        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $job_description;?></span>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($hire_dateError)?'error':'';?>">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
      <div class="controls">
  <input name= "hire_date" type="date" required placeholder="Hire Date" 
    title="Hire Date" value="<?php echo !empty($hire_date)?$hire_date:'';?>">
   <?php if (!empty($hire_dateError)): ?>
        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $hire_date;?></span>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($emailError)?'error':'';?>">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
      <div class="controls">
  <input name="email" type="email" required placeholder="Email" 
    title="Email ID" value="<?php echo !empty($email)?$email:'';?>">
   <?php if (!empty($emailError)): ?>
        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $email;?></span>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div><div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($messageError)?'error':'';?>">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
      <div class="controls">
  <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5" required placeholder="Message" 
    title="Comments"value="<?php echo !empty($message)?$message:'';?>"></textarea>
   <?php if (!empty($messageError)): ?>
        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $messager;?></span>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

this is the action 
  </div> <div class="form-actions">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
              <a class="btn" href="index.php">Back</a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `id` is the last parameter in the query, so it needs to be the last element in the array. If you use positional params then the order of the elements in the parameters array needs to correspond. Alternatively you can use named placeholders: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#example-1028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you need to change the execute line to this:

$q->execute(array($first_name, $sur_name, $company, $location, $supervisor, $department,$job_description, $hire_date, $email, $message, $id));